# Как сохранить cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookie

При загрузки главной страницы `mainpage.com` срабатывает анимация `$("header").addClass("active");`, на этой же странице есть переходы на внутренние страницы `mainpage.com/innerpage`, когда мы заходим во внутреннюю страницу, а потом возвращаемся обратно на главную, срабатывает снова анимация, как можно отключить ее при повторном заходе на эту страницу, я так понимаю это можно сделать с помощью `cookie`, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Дело в том, что как раз проще это сделать через [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) или [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

> Свойство localStorage позволяет получить доступ к локальному Storage объекту. localStorage аналогичено свойству sessionStorage. Разница только в том, свойство sessionStorage хранит данные в течение сеанса (до закрытия браузера), в отличие от данных,  находящихся в свойстве localStorage, которые не имеют ограничений по времени хранения и могут быть удалены только с помощью JavaScript.

```
var isShow = !!parseInt(localStorage.getItem('isShow'));
if(isShow) {
    $("header").addClass("active");
}
```

Установить в хранилище можно  `localStorage.setItem('isShow', 0); // или 1`

Как одной строкой всё проверять и устанавливать/удалять класс:

```
$("header")[parseInt(localStorage.isShow) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']("active");
```

Comment: И лишний трафик не гоняем..

Comment: @vp_arth вот вот

Comment: localStorage.setItem('isShow', 0); // или 1 а что именно дает значение 0 или 1?  и зачем мы пишем !!parseInt перед (localStorage.getItem('isShow')), можете обьяснить пожалуйста

Comment: у нас есть 2 состояния: не показывать анимацию `localStorage.setItem('isShow', 0);`  (положение 0), показывать - `localStorage.setItem('isShow', 1);` ( положение 1).
localStorage хранит только строковые данные и соответственно `localStorage.setItem('isShow', false);` мы не можем потому что false будет строкой "false" или "true" и  если привести к типу boolean, то будет всегда true.

Comment: Поэтому мы используем число, тоесть у нас будет записано "0" или "1", но это всё равно строка её надо привести к типу number. Приведение к такому типу проще всего сделать через `parseInt`.
Тут мы уже пишем `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('isShow'))` - из localStorage получить isShow и привести данные к number в частности integer. Поcледний штрих для красоты привести к boolean через двойное отрицание !! (не не). Можно также использовать функцию Boolean

Comment: Вы вообще можете в 1 строку всё записывать даже. Надо сначала показать анимацию потом Не показывать : `$("header")[parseInt(localStorage.checkAnimate) ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass']("active");` потом установить флаг `localStorage.checkAnimate = 1` и всё, уже анимации нету. Нужно наоборот: `$("header")[parseInt(localStorage.checkAnimate) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']("active");`

Answer (score 7):

Примерно так

```
function setCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    if (nDays == null || nDays == 0)
        nDays = 1;
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue)
            + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString()
            + ";path=/";

}


function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

> сам код вызова

```
  /*Получаем куку*/
    var check = getCookie('show');

/* Значение check  или пусто должно быть или undefined (надо проверить, не помню :) ) */ 

    if(check == ''){
    /*если нет куки показываем анимацию и вставляем куку*/

    setCookie('show', 1,1);
    $("header").addClass("active");
    }
```