# Проблема с проверкой куки

Tags: php, cookie

Сервер не видет куки (хотя они есть).

Код установки куки (Путь к php-файлу, который их устанавливает: Auth/auth.php):

`setcookie("id", "$end");`

Код проверки куки (Путь: index.php):

`if(!isset($_COOKIE['id'])){`

Возможно, проблема из за путей к файлам (файлы не в одной папке), но не знаю, как исправить, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: А что должно происходить, если куки не существует?

Comment: ну вы явно что то не так делаете, как работать с cookie или localstorage смотрите примеры тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-cookie/642900#642900

Comment: @Иван Репин может вы куку проверяете ещё до того, как создали?