# Отображение всплывающего окна через 1 день

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать отображение всплывающего окна на jquery без использования куки, чтобы всплывающее окно отображалось через 15 секунд, а после закрытия через сутки? То есть допустим зашли на главную страницу окно отобразилось через 15 секунд, перешли на другую страницу окно должно отображаться на ней только через сутки?

Comment: «без использования куки» - А что насчет `localStorage`?

Comment: localStorage подойдет если знаете как напишите

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/642897/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-cookie/642900

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  // localStorage недоступен в сниппетах stackoverflow, я эмулирую его 
  const localStorage = emulateLocalStorage(); 
  // получение и проверка даты следующего показа попапа
  const showPopupDate = localStorage.getItem('spDate') || new Date(); 
  if (Date.now() < +showPopupDate) return; 
  // обработчик события закрытия попапа 
  $('#popup').on($.modal.CLOSE, () => {
    showPopupDate.setDate(showPopupDate.getDate() + 1); 
    localStorage.setItem('spDate', showPopupDate); 
    $('#sp-date').text('Следующий показ: ' + showPopupDate.toLocaleString()); 
  }); 
  // отображение попапа
  setTimeout(() => { $('#popup').modal(); }, 15e3); 
});

function emulateLocalStorage() {
  return new (class {
    #store = {}; 
    getItem(name) { return this.#store[name] || null; }
    setItem(name, val) { this.#store[name] = val; }
  })(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-modal@0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-modal@0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.css">

<p id="sp-date"></p>
<div id="popup" class="modal">
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

В сниппете дата показа **не сохраняется** между запусками, так как `localStorage` ненастоящий. На реальной странице - она будет сохраняться.
И конечно же, код эмуляции (функция `emulateLocalStorage`, и ее вызов) на реальной странице совершенно не нужен.

Comment: Библиотека, реализующая попап в примере: https://jquerymodal.com